# LinearLayout Left margin and Right margin not working

Tags: android, android-linearlayout

In my app i have 3 LinearLayout in parent LinearLayout when i am trying to give some space in margin left and margin rignt in my first child but it was not reflecting it was working fine in my second child any one please help me

XML

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/revi_main_layout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/imag_bg"
    android:scaleType = "centerCrop"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:weightSum="1">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_marginTop="140dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:background="#FFFFFF">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="160dp"
                android:id="@+id/revi_fulldes_movieImage"
                android:layout_weight="0"
                android:padding="10dp"/>

        </FrameLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="3">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/revi_fulldes_movietitle"
                android:textSize="18dp"
                android:padding="10dp"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:text="Moviewheewd  ewudwd wedewd w"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/revi_fulldes_movierev_sitename"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
                android:text="simple  jwehd wj dewjd"/>

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="10dp"
        android:background="#00FFFFFF"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="10dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/movie_save"
            android:text="hello"
            android:layout_width="184dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="#4DFFFFFF"/>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/movie_share"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:text="hello world"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_width="164dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:background="#4DFFFFFF"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="10dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="#FFFFFF">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/revi_fulldes_moviedisc_text"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
            android:textSize="@dimen/new_Discription_text"
            android:text="fs dsfjsdf sjf ds fds fsd fds fds  fs fmdmsn fsm fsm fsm fdsm f
              hdfbsd fsdjfhsd dfdsj fsd fdsj fds fds fdsj fsd df
              fsdfhsd dfjsd fhds fjs fds fjds dfs
              dskjfsd fsd fs dfsd dfsd fs dfksd fkds fkds fdks fdsk fdsk f
              f skdf sk fksd fksd fdsk fsk f f  ff df
              f skf skf ksdf  fsk fkdfdkdf ksf
              fks fsk dk fks fdks fdksf sk f
              f skdf skf ksf skdf dsf df dskf kdf kds
              f ksd fdksf dskf df dskf dskf dsk f dsk f
              fksf s fksd "/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="15dp"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="245dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/revi_fulldes_movieyoutube_text"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:gravity="center_vertical"
            android:text="Video"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:textSize="15dp"/>

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="183dp"
            android:id="@+id/revi_fulldes_movieyoutubeImg"
            android:src="@drawable/imag_bg"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"/>

  </LinearLayout>

    <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="15dp"/>


    <View
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="15dp"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

i need margin left and margin right space
here below my image

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Just set your frame layout as left margin and linear layout as right margin check below code

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginTop="140dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp" >

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/revi_fulldes_movieImage"
            android:layout_width="120dp"
            android:layout_height="160dp"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            android:padding="10dp" />
    </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="3"
        android:layout_marginRight="25dp"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/revi_fulldes_movietitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:text="Moviewheewd  ewudwd wedewd w"
            android:textSize="18dp"
            android:textStyle="bold" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/revi_fulldes_movierev_sitename"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
            android:text="simple  jwehd wj dewjd
        " />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="10dp"
    android:background="#00FFFFFF" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/movie_save"
        android:layout_width="184dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:background="#4DFFFFFF"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="hello"
        android:textSize="20dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/movie_share"
        android:layout_width="164dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:background="#4DFFFFFF"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="hello world"
        android:textSize="20dp" />
</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="10dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFFFFF" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/revi_fulldes_moviedisc_text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="25dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
        android:text="fs dsfjsdf sjf ds fds fsd fds fds  fs fmdmsn fsm fsm fsm fdsm f
          hdfbsd fsdjfhsd dfdsj fsd fdsj fds fds fdsj fsd df
          fsdfhsd dfjsd fhds fjs fds fjds dfs
          dskjfsd fsd fs dfsd dfsd fs dfksd fkds fkds fdks fdsk fdsk f
          f skdf sk fksd fksd fdsk fsk f f  ff df
          f skf skf ksdf  fsk fkdfdkdf ksf
          fks fsk dk fks fdks fdksf sk f
          f skdf skf ksf skdf dsf df dskf kdf kds
          f ksd fdksf dskf df dskf dskf dsk f dsk f
          fksf s fksd "
        android:textSize="25sp" />
</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="15dp" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="245dp"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/revi_fulldes_movieyoutube_text"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="35dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical"
        android:text="Video"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/revi_fulldes_movieyoutubeImg"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="183dp"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</LinearLayout>

<View
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="15dp" />

<View
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="15dp" />
```

you can set dimen as per your requirement.Currently i have set 25dp hard coded but its not trustable for all device always practice to use dimen if you are supporting all resolution.

Answer (score 0):

Set the WeightSum attribute to 90 in your parent Linear Layout
And equally distribute the three child with specifying the attribute layout weight
in each of the child to 30. It will equally distribute the layout.
Then use whatever you want insert in your linear layouts.

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:weightSum="90"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
  <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="30"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></LinearLayout>
  <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="30"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></LinearLayout>
  <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_weight="30"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"></LinearLayout>
```